# ChangeFeed and Read all changes to future updates to documents from current time

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

The documentation states that we can `Read all changes to future updates to documents from current time.`  If `StartFromBeginning` is set to false and the continuation token is 0 it will pull all documents from the moment of the query going forward?  If the system isn't generating a lot of inserts/updates there might not be any documents so it would exit pretty quickly.  In the example below, let's say after the first iteration of the `while` there are  no more results, if we sleep there for a period of time indicated by the comment, will the `query.HasMoreResults` be true if there were inserts/updates?

```
 new ChangeFeedOptions
 {
    PartitionKeyRangeId = pkRange.Id,
    StartFromBeginning = true,
    RequestContinuation = continuation,
    MaxItemCount = -1
 });

 while (query.HasMoreResults)
 {
    // stuff since the query was initiated
    // will exit if not much
    // if Thread.Sleep() will query.HasMoreResults return true if items were inserted?
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The documentation states that we can Read all changes to future updates to documents from current time. If StartFromBeginning is set to false and the continuation token is 0 it will pull all documents from the moment of the query going forward?

As far as I know, specifying RequestContinuation property to 0, which does not return changes from current time. You could set it to “*”, like this `RequestContinuation = "*"`. [This documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-change-feed#working-with-the-rest-api-and-sdk) lists scenarios for incremental processing of changes in DocumentDB collections and the request headers for ReadDocumentFeed operations, you will find this.

[image]